# Почему не работает код? cgi-скрипт показывает только первое изображение

Tags: python, cgi

```
searched_list = str(...)).split(',')


i = 0

while i != len(searched_list) + 1:
  answer = searched_list[i] 
  print('<p><img src="http://am.cdnmob.org/pic/v2/gallery/preview/anime-devushki-%s.jpg"></p>'% answer)
  i = i + 1
```

Первое изображение выводит нормально, а последующий уже нет. Только лишь иконки.

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Comment: Ошибку воспроизвести не удалось https://repl.it/FP0R/0

Comment: Добавьте наверху скрипта `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` и добавьте в вопрос полный traceback (если скрипт исключение выбрасывает).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы этот код переписал так:

```
searched_list = str(...)).split(',')

for answer in searched_list:
    print('<p><img src="http://am.cdnmob.org/pic/v2/gallery/preview/anime-devushki-{}.jpg"></p>'.format(answer))
```

Ваш код не работает из-за проблем с индексированием списка, по моему мнению.

Comment: Попробуйте все же ответить на вопросы топикстартера: *"Почему не работает код?", "Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка."*

Comment: @Kromster, не справедливое замечание. Вероятнее всего ошибка вызвана очень опасным алгоритмом с выходом за пределы списка.

Comment: я согласен, что мой ответ не отвечает на вопрос "почему не работает", но он показывает, что надо сделать, чтобы код работал. Я исправил ответ, добавил ответ на вопрос.